# Convert DateTime to long value

Tags: c#

I have the following format in my sql row (DateTime datatype):

00:04:01.

I load it into my program and insert it into a DateTime object. Let's call this object "date".
How can I convert "date" into a long value?

Comment: please use the SEARCH function before asking questions. simple googling of your title brings out several answers.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get long value which represents date and time of your `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) Property

> Gets the number of ticks that represent the date and time of this
>   instance.